# How do I replace my old provisioning profile in Xcode 7?

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode7, provisioning-profile

I've an existing iOS app with a profile that's about to expire, and I'm also about to update the app to the new Ionic Cordova version (the current version is a jQuery Mobile Phonegap app).

The new version builds fine in Xcode and works fine in the emulators.

But there is one problem - it uses the existing (old) provisioning profile and I can't see how to change this. I have a new profile so I'm ready to go.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do this.

Searching the  internet, and indeed the Apple docs, was fruitless.

What had happened (I think) was this:

When I built v2 of my app the Bundle Identifier had a different name. Although I updated this in my Ionic project XCode never "took" the new identifier. When I was double checking all this stuff I found a warning under the Bundle Identifier field that I clicked on and which allowed me to update the provisioning profile. So that error is gone.

Why one can't just click the error and do the same thing only the XCode UI designers know!